# UWP Webview WebRTC portrait mode

Tags: c#, html, webview, uwp

I'm loading a HTML5-Page in a webview to access my Webcam via WebRTC. The camera is rotated by 90 degrees (see CSS below).
How can I achieve that the webview has the same size as my video?

The HTML-Code looks like this:

```
<video autoplay="true" id="videoElement"></video>
```

CSS:

```
        #videoElement {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        background-color: #ffd800;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
```

The JS:

```
    var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
var hdConstraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
        width: 1280, 
        height: 720 
    }
};

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.getUserMedia(hdConstraints, function (stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        localMediaStream = stream;
    }, videoError);
}
```

XAML:

```
    <Grid Background="#FFED6D6D">
    <WebView DefaultBackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" x:Name="wv"  />
    <Button x:Name="btn" Content=":)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="ShowPic"/>
    <Image x:Name="img" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve that the webview has the same size as my video?

Firstly, UWP app has native APIs to access camera, you could just use. Actually there is no need to use `WebView` to load a HTML page to access camera. Details for how to use the native APIs you can reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/simple-camera-preview-access).

Secondly, if you just want to set the `WebView` to the same size as the `video` element has in HTML, you could get the correct size with Javascript functions in HTML and access it with [`InvokeScriptAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__) of `WebView`. For example:

```
private async void wv_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var WebViewWidth = await wv.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "GetWebViewWidth()" });
    var WebViewHeight = await wv.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "GetWebViewHeight()" });
    wv.Height = Convert.ToInt64(WebViewWidth);
    wv.Width = Convert.ToInt64(WebViewHeight);
}
```

And you may calculate the size and the angle with Javascript functions,for example,

```
function VideoGetAngle() { 
    var element = document.getElementById('videoElement');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    var transform = style.getPropertyValue("transform");
    var matrix = transform.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    var a = matrix[0];
    var b = matrix[1];
    var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180 / Math.PI));
    return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
}

function GetWebViewWidth() {
    var videowidth = document.getElementById('videoElement').clientWidth;
    var videoheight = document.getElementById('videoElement').clientHeight;
    var webviewwidth;
    var angle = VideoGetAngle();
    if (angle === 0 || angle === 180 || angle === 360) {
        webviewwidth = videowidth;
    }
    else if (angle === 90 || angle === 270) {
        webviewwidth = videoheight;
    }
    return webviewwidth.toString();
}

function GetWebViewHeight() {
    var videowidth = document.getElementById('videoElement').clientWidth;
    var videoheight = document.getElementById('videoElement').clientHeight;
    var webviewheight;
    var angle = VideoGetAngle();
    if (angle === 0 || angle === 180 || angle === 360) {
        webviewheight = videoheight;
    }
    else if (angle === 90 || angle === 270) {
        webviewheight = videowidth;
    }
    return videowidth.toString();
}
```

But if you actually want the `WebView` to show the `video` for an adaptive size, although you set the `WebView` the same size as the `video` element, it may not work since the `WebView` shows whole HTML page, not only the `video` element. You may also need to [resize](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeto.asp) the HTML window.

Comment: I can not use the APIs, because this application should run on a Raspberry PI. When I use the APIs the webcam uses 100% CPU power. Thats why I chose this workaround. I tried your code, but it's not working properly. Here's one screenshot from the app: https://imgur.com/a/JlPS3 As you can see I added the resolution in the textboxes. They are the same, but the webview is still to big.